# Read data from StreamSocketListener on RFComm bluetooth connected device C#

Tags: c#, bluetooth, windows-runtime, rfcomm

I'm developing an universal application Win8.1 / WP8.1
I'm able to discover and connect to the paired bluetooth devices (Stick readers - Rfid)

This is how I'm connecting

Variables

```
    private IAsyncOperation<RfcommDeviceService> connectService;
    private IAsyncAction connectAction;
    private RfcommDeviceService rfcommService;
    private RfcommServiceProvider rfcommProvider;
    private StreamSocketListener listener;
    private DataReader reader;
    private DataWriter writer;
```

//Connection

```
    public async Task ConnectToServiceAsync(string name)
    {

        DeviceInformation serviceInfo = null;
        foreach (var device in devices)
        {
            if(device.Name == name)
            {
                serviceInfo = device;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (serviceInfo != null)
        {
            this.State = BluetoothConnectionState.Connecting;
            try
            {
                // Initialize the target Bluetooth RFCOMM device service
                connectService = RfcommDeviceService.FromIdAsync(serviceInfo.Id);
                rfcommService = await connectService;
                if (rfcommService != null)
                {
                    rfcommProvider = await RfcommServiceProvider.CreateAsync(rfcommService.ServiceId);

                    // Create a socket and connect to the target 
                    listener = new StreamSocketListener();
                    listener.ConnectionReceived += Listener_ConnectionReceived;

                    connectAction = listener.BindServiceNameAsync(rfcommService.ServiceId.AsString(), SocketProtectionLevel.BluetoothEncryptionAllowNullAuthentication);


                    await connectAction;//to make it cancellable
                    writer = new DataWriter(socket.OutputStream);
                    reader = new DataReader(socket.InputStream);

                    this.State = BluetoothConnectionState.Connected;
                }
                else
                    OnExceptionOccuredEvent(this, new Exception("Unable to create service.\nMake sure that the 'bluetooth.rfcomm' capability is declared with a function of type 'name:serialPort' in Package.appxmanifest."));
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException)
            {
                this.State = BluetoothConnectionState.Disconnected;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.State = BluetoothConnectionState.Disconnected;
                OnExceptionOccuredEvent(this, ex);
            } 


        }
    }
```

//Then wait for a connection over the listener

```
    private async void Listener_ConnectionReceived(StreamSocketListener sender, StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        DataReader inputreader = new DataReader(args.Socket.InputStream);
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                inputreader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
                // Read first byte (length of the subsequent message, 255 or less). 
                uint sizeFieldCount = await inputreader.LoadAsync(1);
                if (sizeFieldCount != 1)
                {
                    // The underlying socket was closed before we were able to read the whole data. 
                    return;
                }

                // Read the message. 
                uint messageLength = inputreader.ReadByte();
                uint actualMessageLength = await inputreader.LoadAsync(messageLength);
                if (messageLength != actualMessageLength)
                {
                    // The underlying socket was closed before we were able to read the whole data. 
                    return;
                }
                // Read the message and process it.
                string message = inputreader.ReadString(actualMessageLength);
                OnMessageReceivedEvent(this, message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (inputreader != null)
                    OnExceptionOccuredEvent(this, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the Bluetooth Stick Reader never send a connection request, it just read the rfid device ID and sends it over the serial port.
So, I'm able to connect to the device but I don't know how to actively listen or read the incoming data.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

RFCOMM communication is Client/Server model. You need to define a server to broadcast the service and a client connected to the service.

As I saw from the code you post, it only includes the server side code which provides the service but there was no client connecting to service. Only when the client connected to the service, the ConnectionReceived event will be fired.
I have written a sample which host the RFCOMM service in a console application and consume the service in Windows Runtime App before ([Code Sample](https://github.com/dream-365/winapp/tree/master/BluetoothPlay)).

The client code is as following:

```
rfcommServiceInfoCollection = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(
                RfcommDeviceService.GetDeviceSelector(RfcommServiceId.ObexObjectPush));

            var count = rfcommServiceInfoCollection.Count;

            Debug.WriteLine("Count of RFCOMM Service: " + count);

            if(count > 0)
            {
                lock (this)
                {
                    streamSocket = new StreamSocket();
                }

                var defaultSvcInfo = rfcommServiceInfoCollection.FirstOrDefault();

                rfcommDeviceService = await RfcommDeviceService.FromIdAsync(defaultSvcInfo.Id);

                if(rfcommDeviceService == null)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Rfcomm Device Service is NULL, ID = {0}", defaultSvcInfo.Id);

                    return;
                }

                Debug.WriteLine("ConnectionHostName: {0}, ConnectionServiceName: {1}", rfcommDeviceService.ConnectionHostName, rfcommDeviceService.ConnectionServiceName);

                await streamSocket.ConnectAsync(rfcommDeviceService.ConnectionHostName, rfcommDeviceService.ConnectionServiceName);
```

By the way, do not forget to add the RFCOMM capabilities in your appxmanifest.

For example:

```
<m2:DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth.rfcomm">
  <m2:Device Id="any">
    <m2:Function Type="name:obexObjectPush" />
  </m2:Device>
</m2:DeviceCapability
```

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, thank you for your time. that it make sense for the client-server model

Answer (score 0):

As Jeffrey said, this is a client/Server model, but in my case the client doesn't have any logic, and is not capable to request any connection.

Thank you for your samples, It helped a lot.

After trying several things I got some code working, and a "server" running and listening in the rfcomm service:

```
    public async Task ConnectToServiceAsync(string name)
    {
        lock(this.interlock)
        {
            readBuffer = String.Empty;
        }
        DeviceInformation serviceInfo = null;
        foreach (var device in devices)
        {
            if(device.Name == name)
            {
                serviceInfo = device;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (serviceInfo != null)
        {
            DeviceName = serviceInfo.Name;

            this.State = BluetoothConnectionState.Connecting;
            try
            {
                // Initialize the target Bluetooth RFCOMM device service
                connectService = RfcommDeviceService.FromIdAsync(serviceInfo.Id);

                rfcommService = await connectService;
                if (rfcommService != null)
                {
                    // Create a socket and connect to the target 
                    socket = new StreamSocket();
                    connectAction = socket.ConnectAsync(rfcommService.ConnectionHostName, rfcommService.ConnectionServiceName, SocketProtectionLevel.BluetoothEncryptionAllowNullAuthentication);

                    await connectAction;//to make it cancellable
                    writer = new DataWriter(socket.OutputStream);
                    reader = new DataReader(socket.InputStream);
                    State = BluetoothConnectionState.Connected;

                    Task taskReceive = Task.Run(async () => { ListenForMessagesAsync(socket); });
                    taskReceive.ConfigureAwait(false);

                }
                else
                    OnExceptionOccuredEvent(this, new Exception("Unable to create service.\nMake sure that the 'bluetooth.rfcomm' capability is declared with a function of type 'name:serialPort' in Package.appxmanifest."));
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException)
            {
                this.State = BluetoothConnectionState.Disconnected;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.State = BluetoothConnectionState.Disconnected;
                OnExceptionOccuredEvent(this, ex);
            } 


        }
    }
```

And the listener in

```
    private async Task ListenForMessagesAsync(StreamSocket localsocket)
    {
        while (socket != null)
        {
            try
            {
                string message = String.Empty;
                DataReader dataReader = new DataReader(localsocket.InputStream);
                dataReader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;

                // Read the message and process it.
                lock (this.interlock)
                {
                    if (!message.Contains("\r\n"))
                        readBuffer = readBuffer + message;
                    else
                    {
                        var data = message.Split('\r');
                        readBuffer = readBuffer + data[0];
                    }
                    if (readBuffer.Length == 15)
                    {
                        readBuffer = readBuffer.Replace("\r\n", "");
                        OnMessageReceivedEvent(this, readBuffer);
                        readBuffer = String.Empty;
                    }
                    if (readBuffer.Length > 15 || (readBuffer.Length < 15 && readBuffer.Contains("\r\n")))
                        readBuffer = String.Empty;
                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (socket != null)
                    OnExceptionOccuredEvent(this, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```